# Copy data from Azure "FILE SHARES" to BLOB containers via data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have setup two datalake Gen2 in one subscription. I am uploading data into FILE SHARES in one of the storage account and try to copy the data to another storage account (Blob container) via data factory. I am not able to set up linked service for data for FILE SHARES from data factory. It only points to Blob containers of the Data Lake.

How do I achieve this? I am trying via data factory as I have to schedule and automatically run this copying once every day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file shares, **Source dataset** should be **Azure File Storage**.

[image]

For linked service, there will be a prompt to ask for **Host**, **User name**, **Password**, to point to your fileshare.
[image]

These **Host**, **Username** and **Password** fields can be obtained when you click on 'Connect' in the Azure file share window.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I had created container with SFTP and I could also create linked service to SFTP from datafactory to copy data from SFTP to data Lake gen2. Now I have to find teh difference between Azure File Storage and SFTP. Vendors will be adding data to SFTP and we are testing.

Answer (score 0):

I could create Linked service for SFTP as below.
[image]